# Problem automating mouse and interacting with Flash apps

Tags: c#, .net, apache-flex, flash, mouse

I written a C# tool that simulates a user interacting with a Windows 7 environment.  It works except when interacting with a couple online flash applications.  Mouse movements and clicks are being generated, but the Flash apps do not receive them.  I am thinking I need to generate lower-level mouse events, but cannot confirm this.

I have tried a couple different mechanisms:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, INPUT[] pInputs, int cbSize);
```

Has anyone come across this problem?  Any ideas how I can generate mouse events that would register with a Flash app?

**Update:**
It looks like the flash apps are receiving the mouse click.  Their click animations are presented when a mouse click is submitted by the C# app.  Still, nothing happens even though the Flash app's mouse click animation displayed.

Comment: Are the flash apps in Internet Explorer windows? Bear in mind that protected mode (http://www.microsoft.com/india/windows/windows-vista/features/IE7-protected-mode.aspx) means that window messages to/from the IE process are affected, it might be that causing the problem. Do any mouse events to elements in the page that are *not* the flash control work?

Comment: I tested it in IE8 & the latest Chrome.  In each I sent mouse events to non-Flash links on a couple pages and they were processed by the browsers.

Comment: what are you trying to do specifically through the flash? there are specific interaction issues with browsers so in built popup blockers etc will kill attempts to open pages unless right after a user interaction. im not sure how it processes this, but it could be that your clicks are not being registered as "human" input, so is being blocked.

Comment: I have a few tools I have made over the years to acquire and mash-up data from various resources (RSS feeds, watching web pages, etc).  It is with these tools that I originally tested with.  I did not put anything in the code to filter human vs. not human actions.  When I was having difficulty I tried it on a few online flash resources (e.g. FaceBook games, flash-only websites, etc.) and had the same issues.

The mouse clicks sometimes works though, which is why I am not thinking that the clicks are filtered.  Rather it seems to be a queuing or timing problem.

Comment: I build another app using Flex Builder and stumbled on something.  I had two button controls overlapped (just didn't delete the bottom one before I compiled) and when I run my tool to auto-click the top one, and the bottom button was clicked instead; not the top one (the only one you can see).  Weird.

Answer (score 1):

Different flash apps respond to different mouse_events.  Have you tried sending mousedown, mouseup, etc?  Also, sometimes you will need to use mousemove first.  I've seen some flash apps where some buttons work by mousedown and others by mouseup.  Also consider disabling the keyboard and mouse just before sending the events and re-enabling after.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into exactly the same problem. the solution I found was not to use the absolute mode when calling `SendInput`, and instead only use relative. This puts more of the work in your code (you need to write tweening code), but makes it so that the border crossing detection code in flash gets fired.

Also, if you are moving the pointer on the same thread as the flash app (i.e. in a browser control), make sure to `Application.DoEen`

Answer (score 0):

Have you investigated FlexMonkey for Flex/AIR UI testing? We've had some success with that.
http://www.gorillalogic.com/flexmonkey

Answer (score 0):

Also try to hide mouse pointer and monitor mouse pointer cordinations(x & Y) in a textbox by trying simple Event.ENTER_FRAME. 
I think the problem is with the browser, not actual flash application. The browser that you use for display flash, I think it must have some properties which alows capturing mouse data by Flash.